# Sun casting square shadow rather than monkey?

Tags: shadows

I am doing a tutorial on game design and have lit my plane with the sun lamp. I am trying to get an object (suzanne) to cast a shadow by switching to GLSL. However, the light itself seems to casting a square shadow. Why is this happening and how can I get rid of it and make the monkey cast a shadow? Thanks.[image: screenshot]

Comment: From your screenshot it is not immediately apparent what might cause the weirdness. Consider uploading your file to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share with us.

Comment: On second look: try switching the Render-Engine (dropdown at the top of the 3D-View) from Blender Game to Blender Internal or Cycles.

Comment: I upvoted this question because I liked th title. 